# residue and singular points

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

Can someone please verify my analysis for the following question?

$f(z)$ = $\frac{1-cos(z)}{z^5}$, find all (isolated) singular points of $f$ and classify them, find residue of f at each singular point.

$f(z)$ has singularity at $z=0$, therefore $$\lim_{z\to0} f(z)$$ = $\frac{1}{\lim_{z\to0} z^5}$ - $\frac{1}{\lim_{z\to0} z^5}$, therefore removable singularity at $z=0$  implies that residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is $0$

Answer (score 1):

The singularity at $z = 0$ is *not* removable. I didn't quite follow your reasoning with the limits, but the reason is because $1-\cos z$ has a second order zero at $z=0$ whereas $z^5$ has a *fifth* order zero. Hence $f$ has a third order pole at the origin.

To compute the residue, it's probably easiest to just use the Taylor expansion of $\cos z$:
$$ \cos z = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - \frac{z^6}{6!} + \dots $$
That means $f(z)$ can be written
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{z^2/2! - z^4/4! + z^6/6! - \dots}{z^5} \\
&= \frac{1}{2!z^3} - \frac{1}{4!z} + \frac{z}{6!} - \dots
\end{align}
The residue is the coefficient of the $1/z$ term: in this case $-1/4! = \boxed{-1/24}$.

And that is the only singularity since the numerator is entire and the origin is the only place where the denominator $z^5 = 0$.